# How to remove Nav-Menu tooltips? (Wp-Globus plugin)

Tags: menus, title, tooltip

I would like to remove all tooltips from my nav-menu, as it cannot detect in which language the title is. I used Wp-Globus plugin for a multi-language site and this issue came after creating the sites in both languages.

[image]

I do not need the tooltips, so I found a tooltip disable plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/remove-tooltips/) but it is not compatible with my theme and after using, it caused several problems.

Do you have an idea or solution to this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What was your efforts?

Comment: That plugin looks fairly simple. I guess you just need to fix the [notttips.js](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/no-title-tooltips/trunk/) script so that it adds to window.onload rather than overwrites it, or use jQuery if you have it loaded on your site. Approaches to do that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15564394/243245

Comment: But this is probably worth reporting to wp-globus as a bug to see if they can fix it too.